# Importing in hierarchical Perl modules into the local namespace

Tags: perl, unit-testing

Situation:

I have a module `Foo::Quux::Bar`, living in `./Bar.pm`. I need to be able to unit test Bar. However, it is not advantageous *due to circumstances beyond my control* to set up a Foo/Quux directory structure.

So what I'd like to do is have some sort of unit_test_use routine that lets me grab Bar.pm and move/copy its functions into the local namespace(Note that Bar has a `package Foo::Quux::Bar` specifier) for my testing pleasure.

Grubbing around in the Perl documentation has not helped me.

Comment: What's your OS? Does `Foo::Quux::Bar` already have an `import` method (*e.g.*, by inheriting from `Exporter`)?

Comment: @Evan: This is a *hack* because of system configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I wrote:

```
sub import_module_into_main
{
   my ($mod_name, $filename) = @_;

   require $filename;

   no strict;
   foreach my $var ( keys( %{$mod_name . "::"}))
   {
      $main::{$var} = ${$mod_name. "::"}{$var};
   }

}
```

Invoke with this: `import_module_into_main("Foo::Quux::Bar", "Bar.pm")`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your Bar.pm exports its functions in the standard way, you can load it with `require` and do the import manually:

```
BEGIN { 
    require 'Bar.pm';        # now the package Foo::Quux::Bar is set up
    Foo::Quux::Bar->import;
};
```

But it's definitely worth looking into setting up the directory structure in the standard way, if you can.

Comment: Put this in a `BEGIN{}` block and it will be just like a fake `use` statement.

Comment: You can just say `require Bar;` you don't need to say `'Bar.pm'`.

Answer (score 4):

The example below uses the following `Bar.pm`:

```
package Foo::Quux::Bar;

use warnings;
use strict;

sub one { 1 }

sub two { "zwei" }

sub three { 0x3333 }

1;
```

In your `test-bar` program, you can install a hook that will use the current directory's `Bar.pm` with

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Basename;

BEGIN {
  sub find_bar {
    my(undef,$name) = @_;

    if (basename($name) eq "Bar.pm") {
      open my $fh, "<", "./Bar.pm" or die "$0: open ./Bar.pm: $!";
      $fh;
    }
  }

  unshift @INC => \&find_bar;
}
```

Hooks in `@INC` are documented in the [perlfunc documentation for `require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html).

Now to import all subs, ignoring any `import` in `Foo::Quux::Bar`,

```
# fake use Foo::Quux::Bar
BEGIN {
  require Foo::Quux::Bar;
  {
    no strict 'refs';
    while (my($name,$glob) = each %Foo::Quux::Bar::) {
      if (*{ $glob }{CODE}) {
        *{ __PACKAGE__ . "::" . $name } = *{ $glob }{CODE};
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Back out in the test code where the `strict` pragma is enabled, we can

```
print map "$_\n", one, two, three;
```

and get the following output:

```
1
zwei
13107
```

Comment: I took your solution's approach and brutally slammed the Foo::Quux::Bar symbol table into main's symbol table, allowing directly testing the functions in Bar. Many good coding practices died to bring me that information...

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure which is the appropriate response: you're welcome or I'm sorry. :-)